# Multiple Input folder location in Mapper

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

Is it possible any way to provide multiple input folder location in Driver class?

I have 4 input folder location in that case how we can specify those all 4 folder location in my driver class so that my mapper can read data from all files in those 4 different folders.

Thanks a lot...

Comment: is it not possible to (say hive) join the data and get one folder. if not why they need to remain separate from each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MultipleInputs class to add your input files.

```
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, inputPath, TextInputFormat.class, MyMapper.class);
```

You can replace the above inputPath to your file location, TextInputFormat.class as your input file format and MyMapper.class to your mapper class.

This way you can add as many files as you need.

Answer (score 0):

In case the data in these 4 locations is different, then you may have to consider creating 4 different mapper classes to read them.Your code would look something similar to below example.Pass your locations as arguments in a sequence while executing the jar.

```
public class MultiplePaths {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    JobConf conf = new JobConf(MultiplePaths.class);
    conf.setJobName("MultipleMappersPaths");

    conf.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    MultipleInputs.addInputPath(conf,new Path(args[0]),TextInputFormat.class,LocationMapper1.class);
    MultipleInputs.addInputPath(conf,new Path(args[1]),TextInputFormat.class,LocationMapper2.class);
    MultipleInputs.addInputPath(conf,new Path(args[2]),TextInputFormat.class,LocationMapper3.class);
    MultipleInputs.addInputPath(conf,new Path(args[3]),TextInputFormat.class,LocationMapper4.class);

    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[2]));
    JobClient.runJob(conf);

  }

}
```

Otherwise, if you have to read similar files from 4 different locations your code should look similar to below example.Pass your locations as arguments in a sequence while executing the jar.

```
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(conf,new Path(args[0]),TextInputFormat.class,LocationMapper.class);
    MultipleInputs.addInputPath(conf,new Path(args[1]),TextInputFormat.class,LocationMapper.class);
    MultipleInputs.addInputPath(conf,new Path(args[2]),TextInputFormat.class,LocationMapper.class);
    MultipleInputs.addInputPath(conf,new Path(args[3]),TextInputFormat.class,LocationMapper.class);
```